# Show legend of geom_line with many geom command in a single plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Hi everyone I represent 2 variable (current and cumulate) of a grouped dataset in a single plot.
The dataset is the follow:

```
> structure(Dt)
   Group Year  Temperature  Cum_Temp
1     H1 2012 11.4487927 11.448793
2     H1 2013  4.5795171 15.903414
3     H1 2014  8.9508743 22.772689
...
10    H2 2012  6.8571429  6.857143
11    H2 2013  1.1428571  8.000000
12    H2 2014  3.4285714  9.714286
...
19   UTC 2012  5.9163059  5.916306
20   UTC 2013  6.3492063  9.956710
21   UTC 2014 16.3059163 19.769120
...
```

I created a color vector:

`plt_col<-rep(c("Blue","Yellow","Red"),each=9)`

and I made the plot:

```
ggplot(Dt, aes(x=Year))+ 
  geom_line(aes(y=Temperature, group=Group),linetype = "solid", color = plt_col, size=1.5)+
  geom_point(aes(y=Temperature, group=Group),shape = 16, color = plt_col, size=3)+
  geom_line(aes(y=Cum_Temp, group=Group),linetype = "longdash", color = plt_col, size=0.8)+
  geom_point(aes(y=Cum_Temp, group=Group),shape = 16, color = plt_col, size=3)
```

I need to show the legend with both, solid and dashed lines, but with many geom_x I am not able.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going about plotting this the wrong way. Try:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

pivot_longer(Dt, 3:4) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value, colour = Group)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = name, size = name)) +
  geom_point(shape = 16, size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "yellow", "red")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("longdash", "solid"), name = "") +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(0.8, 1.5), name = "")
```

[image]